# ASP.NET 5 DI equivalent to Ninject's Bind.ToMethod

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I can't figure out how to bind AutoMapper's `Mapper.Engine` property to the `IMappingEngine` interface using ASP.NET out of the box dependency injection. In Ninject, I imagine (untested) it would look like:

```
Bind<IMappingEngine>().ToMethod(map => Mapper.Engine)
                .InRequestScope();
```

But I'd like to stick with the ASP.NET implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`services.AddScoped<IMappingEngine>(sp => Mapper.Engine)`

Why are you making it scoped and not singleton?

Comment: Thanks! I will be making it singleton, just an error on my part in the original Ninject syntax.

Comment: Then just do `services.AddSingleton<IMappingEngine>(Mapper.Engine);`